# Is the language $L = \{(M,m,n)|\exists x \in \{0, 1\}^n:M$ uses $m$ space on input $x$$\}$ decidable?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, space-complexity

I have stumbled upon this language: $L = \{(M,m,n)|\exists x \in \{0, 1\}^n:M$ uses $m$ space on input $x$$\}$. At first, it looked like an undecidable problem, but I have failed to prove it, and now I am beginning to wonder whether it is actually decidable.

I have designed the following algorithm. Let $G_{M,x}$ be the configuration graph of $M$ on input $x$ (each node represents a snapshot  of $M$, starting from $M(x)$). To decide whether on $x$ we use $m$ space, we visit, DFS-style, each node of $G_{M,x}$ starting from the first node. Each node can be computed from the prior node and we can memorize every node we have encountered so far into a data-structure. Now:

- If we encounter a node which takes up at least $m$ space, we halt and
  say yes.
- If $M$ halts before reaching size $m$ or if we encounter a
  cycle (i.e. find a node we already visited), we stop and say no.

We apply this algorithm for each $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$, looking for at least an $x$ on which we say yes.

**Does this algorithm work? Why or why not?** To me it sounds like it works, but I don't know how to prove it. I guess we need to prove that this algorithm actually decides the problem and that it always halts.

Informally, I believe a way to prove this would be to say that we only have finitely many snapshots which represent less-than-$m$-space configurations: in a finite time, either we encounter some of them more than once (so we enter in a cycle) or we exceed the $m$-space limit. Either way, we halt and answer the question.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111222/why-is-the-run-time-of-an-fn-space-decider-bounded-by-2ofn/111224#111224)

Comment: @Steven nice! thank you very much! do I have to close this question as a duplicate, now?